# Split String based on {} open and curly braces java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String like this

```
String str = {"name":"SachText_singleLineText","value":"text project field"},{"name":"SachSlistSingle_singleSelect","value":"s1"},{"name":"SachYesno_boolean","value":["1"]}
```

I need to split it based on curly braces like this

```
[0] = {"name":"SachText_singleLineText","value":"text project field"}
[1] = {"name":"SachSlistSingle_singleSelect","value":"s1"}
[2] = {"name":"SachYesno_boolean","value":["1"]}
```

Currently, this is what I am trying to do

```
String[] projectfieldsValueArray = str.split("\\{\\{,\\}\\}");
```

I tried with several combinations from net but still not able to split to my requirement. Need help on proper regex need to be used in this scenario.

Comment: I would have thought that you need some content (maybe .*) between the opening and closing brackets no?

Comment: Split by "\\},\\{" and add the removed braced afterwards.

Comment: If you need to do more with the result, it's perhaps better to enclose it in brackets "[" + str + "]" and use a JSON library.

Comment: Is there a way i can split in one go with curly braces?

Comment: Use a lookahead and lookbehind

Answer (score 1):

Using regex is going to be very hard to get it working. Consider this string:

```
{"name":"{SachText},{singleLineText}","value":"text project field"},{"name":"{SachSlist},{Single_singleSelect}","value":"s1"}
```

There are substrings of "},{" inside quotes, making them part of the name itself, so you don't want to split those.

Your strings look like elements of a JSON array. Therefore, put them between "[" and "]" and use a JSON parser, such as Jackson, GSon or Moshi, and it will parse them properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming ur string could be

```
String str = "{\"name\":\"SachText_singleLineText\",\"value\":\"text project field\"},{\"name\":\"SachSlistSingle_singleSelect\",\"value\":\"s1\"},{\"name\":\"SachYesno_boolean\",\"value\":[\"1\"]}";
```

If you need a String in between braces please use regex [{}]
if you need a split string with braces you can prepend "{" and append "}"

```
 String[] arrOfStr = str.split("[{}]");
        for(String a: arrOfStr) {
            System.out.println(  a );
        }
```

O/p: "name":"SachText_singleLineText","value":"text project field"
,
"name":"SachSlistSingle_singleSelect","value":"s1"
,
"name":"SachYesno_boolean","value":["1"]

Comment: I tried with above regex. But i got this as output. [, "name":"SachText_singleLineText","value":"text project field", ,, "name":"SachSlistSingle_singleSelect","value":"s1", ,, "name":"SachYesno_boolean","value":["1"]]

Answer (score 0):

you can try with Pattern Matcher.

```
    String key = "(\\{.*?\\})";
    String str = //your string.;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(key);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `str` taken from Suvarn Banarjee and the hint from Mark Rotteveel:

```
String str = "{\"name\":\"SachText_singleLineText\",\"value\":\"text project field\"},{\"name\":\"SachSlistSingle_singleSelect\",\"value\":\"s1\"},{\"name\":\"SachYesno_boolean\",\"value\":[\"1\"]}";
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)");
```

But again, this looks like JSON to me, so it's usually best to use a JSON library, since I'm pretty sure you're not done with just splitting.